# How to Move the Intercepts of $x^y=y^x$ to (1, 1)

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

In the equation, $x^y=y^x$, which I have modified to $(gx)^{y}=(gy)^{x}$, what would $g$ have to be to make the $f(x)=x$ function to intercept with the hyperbolic function at the point $(1,1)$?

[[image: Graph of <span class=]$gx^y=gy^x$ where $g=1$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1z8n.png)

Comment: Take $g$ to be $e$.

Comment: Do you know about graph shifting? Just subtract what you need from each variable in the written equation. Then you'll literally have the exact same graph, but the intercept is wherever you want.

Comment: I modified the text of the question so that it corresponds to the equation in the picture. If this is not correct please let me know (and ignore my answer below).

Comment: Do you know that you entered in the wonderful world of Lambert function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not quite clear to me. At point (x,y)=(1,1) or any other point where x=y, any real value of g would give equality to the expression  $(gx)^y=(gy)^x$.

In the general case, where x is not necessarily equal y, this rounded value of g=2.71828 will cause equality of the equation and intercept with $y=x$ at point $(1,1)$, hence you get:  $$(2.71828x)^{y}=(2.71828y)^{x}$$.

In fact, in this case the foollowing is true:

$$g=e$$

So we have:

$$(e.x)^{y}=(e.y)^{x}$$.

Where e is the [e-The Famous Math Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

Since you are using Desmos, maybe you don't want an analytic/algebraic detailed solution and the graph would suffice.

See:
[Desmos Plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5mfuwn8i2c)

Comment: I'm sorry the question wasn't clear enough but this is actually exactly what I was looking for. So thank you.

Comment: @ChristianAlbina You are most welcome - I am so glad I could help :)c